# Diffie Hellman Problem

Tags: cryptography

I know that in Diffie Hellman, the final key (from **Bob's point of view** the **final key** is calculated as follows)

> K<sub>B</sub> = (g<sup>x</sup> mod n)<sup>y</sup> mod n, where
>
> ```
> x represents Alice's private no.
> y represents Bob's private no.
> g and n the two public nos.
> ```

which can be evaluated as

> K = (g<sup>xy</sup> mod n) **OR** (g<sup>yx</sup> mod n), where
>
> ```
> x represents Alice's private no.
> y represents Bob's private no.
> g and n the two public nos.
> ```

My question is that *How does `KB = (gx mod n)y mod n` evaluates to `K = (gxy mod n) OR (gyx mod n)`*. Does the **mod operator** has a ***property*** where `(gx mod n)y mod n` evaluates to `gxy mod n`?

Comment: It is a result of $(a\mod n)\cdot{(b \mod n)}=(ab \mod n)$.

Comment: Ok so (g^x mod n).(g^x mod n)...(g^x mod n)...(y times) basically means (g^(y.x) mod n) and that is a property right?

Comment: Indeed :) (*minimum chars*)

Comment: I'm really sorry but I missed a `mod n` in  `(g^x mod n)^y` (I have now edited the question) so should your answer be `(a mod n).(b mod n) = (ab mod n) mod n`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misconceptions about what $\text{mod}$ means. Let $p$ be an integer, then the "object" $x\text{ mod }p$ is the equivalence class of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, that is to say the image of $x$ under the quotient map
$$\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},$$
which for simplicity we'll write $[x]$. It is easy to check that indeed $[x]^a = [x^a]$, which is the property you wanted.

**Remark:** all numbers considered here are integers.

Comment: @Bateman What? No, I meant exactly what I wrote.