# Why can we perform the following simplification in the Diffie-Hellman problem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I essentially have the same exact question as this one: [Diffie Hellman Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854742/diffie-hellman-problem), which unfortunately doesn't have any good answers that clear up my confusion. There is one answer that is highly technical and that I don't understand. The comments seem to be on the right track, but I don't follow.

What I do understand is the following:

1. Alice and Bob agree on two public numbers, $g$ and $n$.
2. Alice chooses a private number, $a$, such that $1 <= a <= n$.
3. Bob chooses a private number, $b$, such that $1 <= b <= n$.
4. Alice computes $g^a (\text{mod n})$ and sends the result to Bob.
5. Bob computes $g^b (\text{mod n})$ and sends the result to Alice.
6. Upon receiving $g^a(\text{mod n})$ from Alice, Bob performs: $(g^a)^b (\text{mod n})$.
7. Upon receiving $g^b(\text{mod n})$ from Bob, Alice performs: $(g^b)^a (\text{mod n})$.
8. These are identical, and the result is used as the key for their communication.

Everything makes sense for me up until step 6. Bob received $g^a (\text{mod n})$ from Alice, so how can he perform $(g^a)^b$ if he does not know the value of $a$? Similarly, Alice received $g^b (\text{mod n})$ from Bob, so how can she perform $(g^b)^a$ if she doesn't know the value of $b$?

Said differently, Bob needs to calculate this:

$$
(g^a \text{mod n})^b (\text{mod n})
$$

What property of modular arithmetic allows him to simplify it to the following?

$$
g^{ab} (\text{mod n})
$$

Comment: So you’re essentially asking: why is $(x\text{ mod }n)^k\text{ mod }n =x^k\text{ mod }n$? Just write $x=a+bn$ and see what happens.

Comment: @FShrike Yep, that's my question.

Comment: @FShrike So if $x = a + bn$, where the $a$ and $b$ here are not related to the original problem and we're just representing $x$ as its divisor times the quotient plus the remainder, then rearranging for $a$ gives: $a = x - bn$, which is precisely the remainder, or $x \mod n$. So Substituting gives $(x-bn)^k \mod n$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Sure thing, I should have checked for the dupe first